# Using TOP along with condition in Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table variable in my query, lets say it has StudentId, TotalMarks, Rank and the records in this table variable are stored in the order of Rank.

My  stored precedure query takes StudentId as a parameter.

Now I would like to get top 3 students i.e students with Rank 1,2,3

```
SELECT TOP 3 [StudentId], [TotalMarks], [Rank]
FROM @TableVariable
```

Now along with the TOP 3, I need to get the StudentId, [TotalMarks], [Rank] of the @StudentId which is passed as a parameter to the stored procedure.

I can do a `UNION ALL` to the above query use below query

```
SELECT [StudentId], [TotalMarks], [Rank]
FROM @TableVariable
WHERE [StudentId] = @StudentId
```

I am checking if there is any other better way of doing this without `UNION All`.

Comment: Union all seems reasonable without any information to the contrary, but note that your first `TOP` query should probably have `ORDER BY [Rank]` at the end, as using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is not well defined.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen While inserting data into my TableVariable i have used ORDER BY [Rank] , do u still think there is a need to have  ORDER BY [Rank] again in the SELECT statement ?

Comment: Sample data and expected results please! If you don't have an `order by` you will be getting any 3 rows in any order SqlServer chooses

Comment: Yes, @Juan , the order you `INSERT` the data into a table and the order data is retrieved from said table are completely unrelated. Without an explicit `ORDER BY` SQL Server is free to return the rows in any arbitrary order, and so your "`TOP`" 3 will also be 3 arbitrary rows.

Comment: Also to clarify your assumption - you have a table, a table is by definition an unordered set, you cannot assume any ordering unless you specify it.

Comment: Not only is the order of insert and select unrelated, the `ORDER BY` in an `INSERT` is completely ignored (unless a `TOP` is used).

Comment: Got it, i have added.

Comment: Add an order by what your top is relevant. 
If a student is in both queries you will have a duplicate using "union all" if you don't want it use a simple "union"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ORDER BY` and `SELECT TOP 3`, you can use `WHERE RANK IN (1,2,3)`  as below

```
SELECT [StudentId], [TotalMarks], [Rank]
FROM @TableVariable
WHERE [Rank] IN (1,2,3)
UNION ALL
SELECT [StudentId], [TotalMarks], [Rank]
FROM @TableVariable
WHERE [StudentId] = @StudentId
```

Answer (score 1):

`ROW Number` is an another option:

Here 106 is an Student ID need to be Search parameter

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, MRK INT,RANK INT)

DECLARE @ID INT=106

INSERT INTO @T VALUES(101,100,1),(102,99,2),(103,98,3),(105,98,5),(106,98,6)

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY RANK) AS RW
FROM @T) S
WHERE (RW<=3 OR ID=@ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If rank is really 1, 2, 3 (as your question implies), then you can get the top three using:

```
where rank <= 3
```

rather than `top (3)`.

If that is the case, then just use:

```
select tv.*
from @TableVariable tv
where tv.studentid = @studentid or
      rank <= 3
order by tv.rank;
```